# How can I make my background picture?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In Android Application (Eclipse) How I can make an image as background for a View?

Comment: For your app or for eclipse? You are very unspecific ;) could you also add some code to show what you've done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programatically you can add a background to a view using:

```
View view = yourView;
view.setBackgroundDrawable(yourDrawable);
//or with
view.setBackgroundResource(resid);
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** I am assuming you want to make a picture background of an `Activity`.

**-** Set the `android:background` attribute.

**Eg:**

`android:background="@drawable/my_picture"`